# Hiding row based on variable row number in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a loop that searches every filled cell in column "J" in sheet2, and hides the corresponding row in sheet1.  For example, if cell J1 was "30", row 30 in sheet1 would be hidden.  Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub test()

    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long, value As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    Set ws = Sheet2
    lrow = ws.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lrow
        value = ws.Cells(i, 10).value
        cell = "A" & value
        Sheet1.[cell].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next i

End Sub
```

Everything is working except for the line "Sheet1.[value].entirerow.hidden=true".  I'm probably using incorrect syntax.  Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: `Sheet1.Rows(Value).Hidden = True`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!